# Inducing a partial ordering on every nonempty subset of X given a partial ordering on X.

Tags: analysis, order-theory

I'm browsing through the introduction section of Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications*, and I've read a claim that I can't make sense of:

> [...] a partial ordering on $X$ naturally induces a partial ordering on every nonempty subset of $X$.

What is the construction of such a naturally induced partial ordering? And what is a non-trivial example of this partial ordering on subsets of $X$? (I have a sense that this is the sort of idea that may be obvious in hindsight.)

---

**Edit:**
I misunderstood the claim. I was thinking that given some partial ordering on, say, the set $X = \{a, b\}$ that there was a naturally induced partial ordering on the set $X' = \{\{a\}, \{b\}, \{a, b\}\}$.

Comment: It just means if a>b>c then a>b and a>c and b>c pretty much.

Comment: If $S\subset X$ and $a$, $b\in S$ the $a\le b$ in $S$ iff $a\le b$ in $X$.

Comment: The empty set is ordered by the empty relation.